# Trouble moving some functions from one file to another C++

Tags: c++, header, g++

I am working on a project in my C++ class.  I turned in a previous assignment where I implemented a command line version of the game Hex, with a minimal AI to play against the player.  For my current assignment, I am expanding the AI with some Monte Carlo stuff.  In preparation for that, I am trying to move the AI decisions into its own separate class (It was originally just called as a function in the file containing main).  G++ is giving me horrendous compiler errors that I don't understand, so hopefully someone can point out where my syntax errors are, because I am new to C++ and have been unable to track them down, and g++ errors aren't especially helpful all the time.  The contents of the functions in HexAI.cpp should not be the problem, since they were copy-pasted from their original location and I have also moved the global variables they referenced.  The only thing that I added was the class definition, the constructor/destructor, and the HexAI::getMove() function.  The vector board declaration is a 2d vector of integers, used to hold a 0 if the spot is taken, 1 if player 1 has it, or 2 if player 2 has it.  Thanks in advance for all the help, and since I am new, feel free to point out anything I missed in as much detail as you feel necessary.  I just want to learn whats going on and move on, since I've been stuck on this all afternoon.

**HexAI.h**

```
#include <vector>
#ifndef HEXAI_H
#define HEXAI_H


typedef vector<int> intvec;

class HexAI{
    public:

    HexAI(int s);
    ~HexAI();
    int* getMove(vector<intvec> board);

    private:

    void AIRandomMove(vector<intvec> board);
    void AI (vector<intvec> board);

    int compMadeMove; //decides if it is the first turn or not
    int compMoveI; //row
    int compMoveJ; //column
    int size; //size of the board
};

#endif
```

**HexAI.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "HexAI.h"

using namespace std;

typedef enum playerColor{
    neutral, p1, p2
}playerColor;

typedef vector<int> intvec;

HexAI::HexAI(int s){
    compMoveI = 0;
    compMoveJ = 0;
    compMadeMove = false;
    size = s;
    srand(time(NULL));
}

~HexAI::HexAI(){
    //nothing needs to be deleted
}


//when it throws its hands in the air
void HexAI::AIRandomMove(vector<intvec> board){
    bool acceptableMove = false;
    while( not acceptableMove){
        int a = rand() % (size - 1);//it has trouble when its randomly on the bottom
        int b = rand() % size;
        if(board[a][b] == neutral){
            acceptableMove = true;
            compMoveI = a;
            compMoveJ = b;
        }
    }
}


//makes a decision based on the board, sets 2 variables
//that are read in as the move later on
//tries to go straight top to bottom, move left or right if that spot is taken.
//goes for a random move if it can't decide how to move
void HexAI::AI (vector<intvec> board){
    //catch seg faults that show up 1 turn after random indexes put it on the bottom row
    if(compMadeMove and compMoveI == (size - 1) ){ //if it randomly ends up on the bottom, move it to the top and start over, here to fix seg faults
        compMadeMove = false;
    }
    //determine starting position
    if( not compMadeMove ){//first move, pick a spot on the top
        bool goodguess = false;
        int startPos = rand() % size;
        while(!goodguess){
            if(board[0][startPos] != 0){
                startPos = rand() % size;
            }else{
                goodguess = true;
            }
        }
        compMoveI = 0;
        compMoveJ = startPos;
        compMadeMove = true;
    }else{//later moves
        int potentialMove = board[compMoveI + 1][compMoveJ];
        if(potentialMove == neutral){//try to just move down one
            compMoveI += 1;
        }else{//try downleft or just left or right
            potentialMove = board[compMoveI + 1][compMoveJ - 1];
            if(potentialMove == neutral){//downleft
                compMoveI += 1;
                compMoveJ -= 1;
            }else{//downLeft was taken, go left or right
                potentialMove = board[compMoveI][compMoveJ + 1];
                if(potentialMove == neutral){//go right
                    compMoveJ += 1;
                }else{//hopefully left works?
                    potentialMove = board[compMoveI][compMoveJ - 1];
                    if(potentialMove == neutral){
                        compMoveJ -= 1;
                    }else{//ARG I give up, random
                        AIRandomMove(board);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(compMoveI < 0 or compMoveI >= size or compMoveJ < 0 or compMoveJ >= size){
        AIRandomMove(board);
    }
    cout << endl << "My move is " << compMoveI << " " << compMoveJ << endl << endl;
}

int* HexAI::getMove(vector<intvec> board){
    AI(board);
    int* ij = new int[2];
    ij[0] = compMoveI;
    ij[1] = compMoveJ;
    return ij;
}
```

**g++ errors**

```
g++ -c -Wall HexAI.cpp
In file included from HexAI.cpp:5:
HexAI.h:6: error: expected initializer before â<â token
HexAI.h:13: error: expected â;â before â(â token
HexAI.h:17: error: âvectorâ has not been declared
HexAI.h:17: error: expected â,â or â...â before â<â token
HexAI.h:18: error: âvectorâ has not been declared
HexAI.h:18: error: expected â,â or â...â before â<â token
HexAI.cpp:23: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before â::â token
HexAI.cpp:29: error: prototype for âvoid HexAI::AIRandomMove(std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >)â does not match any in class âHexAIâ
HexAI.h:17: error: candidate is: void HexAI::AIRandomMove(int)
HexAI.cpp:47: error: prototype for âvoid HexAI::AI(std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >)â does not match any in class âHexAIâ
HexAI.h:18: error: candidate is: void HexAI::AI(int)
HexAI.cpp:96: error: no âint* HexAI::getMove(std::vector<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >, std::allocator<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >)â member function declared in class âHexAIâ
make: *** [HexAI.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `std::` in front of all the `vector` declarations in the header will fix most of the error for example:

```
typedef vector<int> intvec;
```

should be:

```
typedef std::vector<int> intvec;
```

You mixed up the `~` in your destructor implementation, this:

```
~HexAI::HexAI(){
```

should be:

```
 HexAI::~HexAI(){
```

and I would discourage to the use of `using namespace std;` is saves you a little typing but can cause you problems later on.

Comment: Good catch on that destructor, silly me.  I am still curious about the header file thing, I had a #include <vector> as the first line of that file.  Why doesn't it find the vector from that?

Comment: @user2309865 It does not work b/c `vector` is in the `std` namespace, in the `cpp` file you have `using namespace std;` which means you can access everything in `std` without using `std::`. It took me a couple of times before I realized what was wrong with the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
typedef vector<int> intvec;
```

to

```
typedef std::vector<int> intvec;
```

Answer (score 0):

- There's no `using namespace std` in HexAI.h, so it doesn't know what "vector" is. You should use `std::vector` instead.
- `~HexAI::HexAI` should be `HexAI::~HexAI`

Otherwise it should compile; hope I could help.

Comment: I read on another c++ site that you should never use using namespace statements on header files.  I guess that threw me off.  Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't, because then files which include that header are forced to use the namespace, and you can end up with conflicts. Which is why namespaces exist in the first place. So use std::vector in the header file.